# Patterns for maintenance login

Tags: login

Are there any reliable strategies to implement a login mechanism that will allow access to an application for maintenance purposes? Kind of like how some routers have a list of default logins that technicians can use. But the way routers do it is insecure, and I was wondering if there are better ways to implement this sort of access control.

EDIT: Here's a possible solution I came up with. Generate a list of passwords for a given time window, say a month, with a different password for every day. This list would exist in the software in encrypted form. Maintenance technicians would have access to this list, and its use would be logged so we know when to block access should unauthorized personnel gets a copy of the list and use it to log in. Periodic updates would renew the application's password table.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Are you asking about ways to implement a [back door](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backdoor_(computing))?  If so, the correct answer is "don't".

Comment: @gnat: Updated my question with what I could come up with.

Comment: @Dan: How else can I address the situation where I need to provide support to a client, and he doesn't remembers any of his logins?

Comment: I would build in a standard "I forgot my password" reset mechanism for the client to use.

Comment: @Dan: The system in question is a point of sale system. I'm not really familiar with other companies POS systems, but a 'forgot my password' option sounds weird to me in this context.

Comment: When you get into point of sales devices, you find you will want to thoroughly review the PCI requirements.  https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf In particular, 6.3.1, 8.1, and 8.5.8

Comment: @MichaelT: Thank you! Looks very relevant to my situation.

Comment: @DavidMcDavidson PCI-DSS is more focused on the actual business that will be taking payments, you need to also look at [PA-DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PA-DSS_v3.pdf) for the requirements on the software side. Note that the link from MichaelT is to version 2 of the standard but as of this month [version 3](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/DSS_and_PA-DSS_Change_Highlights.pdf) is actually out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing an electronic backdoor is a ... terrible idea.  Don't do it.  It doesn't take much searching to find a number of cases where this "feature" blows up and gets the offending company slathered with horrific mentions in the news.

Your best option would be to provide a reset switch within the device itself.  And please note that's within the system, not on the outside of the system. That forces an attacker to have physical access to the system before they can reset passwords.  Obviously, you should provide a lock to secure the physical system in order to discourage unauthorized access.

You should also assume that *any* time that reset switch is thrown that the system has been compromised.  So you need to provide a means to audit / validate the settings of the system.  And you need to provide some indicator on the system itself to show that it's in an untrusted state.  Ideally, you'll lock it out from being able to process transactions or do anything else until the audit check is cleared.

You'll also need to identify a way to protect any data that may have been stored on that system.  Assume that "reset password" means "someone attacking the device" and then look for ways to harden that data from any access until the system is validated and determined to be trustworthy again.

If you're thinking "wow, that's an incredible pain in the rear" then you'd be right.  But that's the point.  A rogue point of sale system represents a significant liability for the owning company.  You want these types of resets to be difficult to achieve, and you want to make sure any attack against the system is obvious to everyone else.

---

In your comment, you mention this is for point of sale systems.  MichaelT's comment with a link to some [PCI security documents](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf) would be a good place to continue your research.

Comment: I understand now that a backdoor is a bad idea. What's the industry standard solution to do maintenance on a client's system? Do I ask the client to create a maintenance login and provide me with its details?

Comment: From their point of view, that's the best approach.  Because it means they have a specific ID to track your actions on the system.  On some non-PCI but heavily regulated systems, we created accounts for _each_ vendor employee that would be touching the system.  That way we knew if George or Jane had made the change.